# Select foreign columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, foreign-keys

Is it possible to select data in a foreign table directly, instead of using the `JOIN` keyword?

Like in a book - chapter example with a `FOREIGN KEY` defined:

```
SELECT chapter.title FROM book WHERE book.title='some title'
```

Comment: some dbms, i know intersystems caché for example, allows you to do something like this, but not mysql

Comment: Without joins in a *direct* query is not possible. But you can create a `VIEW` on the tables and query it directly for the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer **NO**. Look at your below query, if you don't join with `Book` table then how will you define that the selected chapter represents which book(s) (OR) are they orphan chapters dropped from sky. You want to join with `Book` table; so that you can relate the chapters with specific books and can say that chapter 1 - belong to book xyz.

```
SELECT chapter.title FROM book WHERE book.title='some title'
```

Comment: The relation would be defined by the foreign key. Book: id - title. Chapter: id- book_id-title. I expected this to be the most import function of a foreign key.

Comment: That's true, but while querying you will have to relate both the entities on that FK column. Else, outcome result is kind a divorced.

Comment: Why should I define foreign keys?

Comment: Exactly for this purpose you should define FK. To represent a relationship b/w two entities in a entity relationship model.

Answer (score 1):

In a word - no.
Any column you select must come from a table/view/subquery/whatever that's either in the `from` clause or one of the `join` clauses.